# AWS EKS "0/3 nodes are available: 3 Too many pods" Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have 3 node group t3a.micro and I installed ebs csi provider and storage-class.

I want deploy statefulset on mysql
this is my manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql-statefulset
spec:
  serviceName: mysql-service
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:   
        app: mysql-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pvc-test
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: pvc-test
    spec:
      storageClassName: gp2-retain
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ] 
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Warning  FailedScheduling  20s (x16 over 20m)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 Too many pods.

Comment: Guessing, based on the error message you posted. You are already running too many pods on all the nodes, which is causing failure in further resource allocation.  you can check the number of pods on each node using `kubectl get pod -A|grep <node-name>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FailedScheduling: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257796/failedscheduling-0-3-nodes-are-available-3-insufficient-pods)

Comment: This is deeper error and related to AWS `t3a.micro` instance size, particularly to amount of network interfaces. [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64972286/15537201) was already rased. Let us know if this helps you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS EKS - Only 2 pod can be launched - Too many pods error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965832/aws-eks-only-2-pod-can-be-launched-too-many-pods-error)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [AWS EKS - Only 2 pod can be launched - Too many pods error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965832/aws-eks-only-2-pod-can-be-launched-too-many-pods-error)

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI, `t3a.micro` type has

```
Maximum network interfaces: 2
Private IPv4 addresses per interface: 2 
IPv6 addresses per interface: 2
```

But EKS deploys `DaemonSets` for e.g. CoreDNS and kube-proxy, so some IP addresses **on each node** is already allocated.

Possible fix is just upgrade your instance to be a more capable type.